# Clipping with iterate feature class is only returning some clipped shapefiles with wrong names

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, iteration

I am trying to create a tool that will clip multiple features (point, line, and polygon) in a geodatabase to a drainage area. I have it set up like this:

[image: Model builder setup]

[image: Dialogue Box]

Since I have to set this up for someone else to use it, I am testing the tool on a simple geodatabase of national roads, counties, congressional districts, and state capitals (clipping to a state boundary). However, when I run the tool, it only produces two files in the destination geodatabase, _cliproads and _clipstate_caps (the clipped roads and state capitols file). And when I examine the _clipstate_caps layer, it is a polygon layer instead of a point layer, and it contains the clipped features of the congressional districts layer.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The model runs fine from the ModelBuilder screen. It does everything it is supposed to. Problems only arise when I try to run it from the dialogue box.